# Search a string In Xml Files And Send Email

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple batch file as below but I couldn't work successfuly,
I want to do this,

1) I have some xml file ( c:\xmlfile*.xls )
2) I want to find a string in xml files ( FAILURE )
3) If I find this string, batch file send an email else nothing

```
@echo on
CD c:\xmlfile
findstr /C:"FAILURE" *
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
  GOTO SENDMAIL
) ELSE (
  GOTO NOTHING
)
:SENDMAIL
bmail ********
:NOTHING
```

Could you please correct this batch file ?

Regards

Comment: I do not understand your 1st point. Is it one file or multiple files? Are they located in c:\ or in other folder? Please edit - it's unreadable at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

some previous caveats

1. xls extension is usually for Excel files, not XML files.
2. I assume you mistyped c:\xmlfile*.xls where you really meant c:\xmlfile\*.xls
3. the right way of checking ERRORLEVEL is `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ...`
4. there are many alternatives for batch send mail. I use `blat` so I assume you have it installed and configured.

so, try this to get you on track...

```
@echo off
pushd c:\xmlfile
findstr /i "FAILURE" *.xls
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo FAILURE not found
) ELSE (
  blat <filename> -to <recipient>
)
popd
```